# Register FilterRegistrationBean without @Bean annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I'm trying to register any number of FilterRegistrationBeans dynamically based on configuration proprties. How can I register a FilterRegistrationBean withtout a method annotated with @Bean.

My working solution is to add a fixed amount of methods annotated with the @Bean annotation which procudes a lot of code and is not flexible.

```
@Bean
@Conditional(ConfigConditionFoo.class)
public FilterRegistrationBean filter6() {
    return new FilterRegistrationBean(...);
}

public static class ConfigConditionFoo extends AllNestedConditions {
    public ConfigCondition6() { super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN); }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dummy", value =  "filters[5].url")
    static class OnEnabled { }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dummy", value =  "filters[5].filter-method", havingValue = "servlet", matchIfMissing = true)
    static class OnServletFilter{ }
}
```

I've tried the following:

- Register to the application context.
- Use the ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory and add the bean to the initializers.

The problem is that the order of the FilterRegistrationBean is not picked up. The filter is always executed last.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try @Order(n) where n is the number of order to be executed over your class (filter). The lower the number, the higher the precedence

Comment: I wan&#39;t to configure the order based on the property configuration and add it in the FilterRegistrationBean. I want to configure a rate limit where one is executed before all other and one e.g. after spring security based on logged in users. So a hard coded order doesn&#39;t work here.